# How often is the meta participation ranking updated?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, users-page, participation

On per-site meta Users page, instead of reputation tab, there is a participation tab, e.g. on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation):

> [image]

How often is the list of users by meta participation refreshed? I'd assume every hour, because that's how often your meta reputation is updated to match your main site reputation.

Comment: Worth to mention that it exists [even here on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation), even though there's no link to it on the users page itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard and not worth to mention that `?tab=reputation` exists on child meta even though there's no link to it.

Comment: @Pandya why not? Worth as well, actually I wasn't aware of that myself. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard btw, it even exist on every main site though there's no link.

Comment: @Pandya true, but on SO it get stuck so I didn't mention it.